# Cleaning string for XML inserting in PHP

Tags: php, xml

I currently have a script that was not written by me that takes information from a comment fields in the database and puts it into a xml files. as you can guess there is a lot of bad chars and just junk that can be in the this field.

In the past a lot of developers have tried adding functionality to the software to try to fix this up (a lot of patches) but we still get a few that get through.

before I go down the insanity path trying to work out all possibilities, does anyone have a simple way of doing this, take any string and clean it up for an xml files.

I have tried:

```
htmlspecialchars();
htmlentities();
```

but they don't seen to get everything for XML.

Also things like & to `&amp;` is fine, but `&amp;` to `&amp;amp;` is not good

Maybe a function or libary `xmlentities()` or somthing :)

Comment: What about putting your bad content inside 'CDATA' tags?

Comment: The easiest way obviously is to use an XML writer library, which takes care of the entire minutiae of XML syntax for you.